# How to implement class/object metadata in Python?

Tags: python, class, coding-style, metadata

I am working on a structured data analysis framework which is based on streaming data between  [nodes](http://packages.python.org/brewery/node_reference.html). Currently nodes are implemented as subclasses of root Node class provided by the framework. For each node class/factory I need metadata, such as list of node's attributes, their description, node output. The metadata might be both: for end-users in front-end application or for programming use - some other stream management tools. In the future there will be more of them.

(Note that I just started to learn python while writing that code)

Currently the metadata are provided in a class variable

```python
class AggregateNode(base.Node):
    """Aggregate"""

    __node_info__ = {
        "label" : "Aggregate Node",
        "description" : "Aggregate values grouping by key fields.",
        "output" : "Key fields followed by aggregations for each aggregated field. Last field is "
                   "record count.",
        "attributes" : [
            {
                 "name": "keys",
                 "description": "List of fields according to which records are grouped"
            },
            {
                "name": "record_count_field",
                 "description": "Name of a field where record count will be stored. "
                                "Default is `record_count`"
            }
        ]
    }
```

More examples can be found [here](https://github.com/Stiivi/brewery/blob/master/brewery/nodes/field_nodes.py).

I feel that it can be done in much cleaner way. There is one restriction: as nodes are custom subclasses classes, there should be minimal interference with potential future attribute names.

What I was thinking to do was to split the current **node_info**. It was meant to be private to the framework, but now I realize it has much wider use. I was thinking about using node_ attributes: will have common attribute namespace, not taking too much of names from potential custom node attributes.

My question is: What is the most common way of providing such metadata in python programs? Single variable with a dictionary? Multiple variables, one for each metadata attribute? (this would conflict with the restriction) Custom class/structure? Use some kind of prefix, like node_* and use multiple variables?

Comment: Just to add another example of using the metadata: stream network will be configurable through a dictionary with node+attribute+value tuples and the configuring function should take care of default values and prevent setting of protected attributes under certain circumstances (like some attributes will be settable only in code, others will be open to an UI).

Comment: Don't create custom names that start and end with a double underscore. I don't have the link right now, but they are considered reserved so that any use of them is clearly referring to a language feature and not a user defined variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is some "standard" way to store custom metadata in python objects, but as an example, the python implementation of dbus adds attributes with the ["`_dbus`" prefix](http://codesearch.google.com/#-ilQSjch8tg/dbus-python-0.80.1/dbus/decorators.py&q=lang%3apy%20func._dbus_is_method&type=cs&l=123) to the published methods and signals.

Comment: Used plain, public `node_info`.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the functionality you're describing overlaps with [epydoc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/):

```
>>> class AggregateNode(base.Node):
...     r"""
...     Aggregate values grouping by key fields.
... 
...     @ivar keys: List of fields according to which records are grouped
... 
...     @ivar record_count_field: Name of a field where record count will be
...                               stored.
...     """
...     record_count_field = "record_count"
...     
...     def get_output(self):
...         r"""
...         @return: Key fields followed by aggregations for each aggregated field.
...                  Last field is record count.
...         """
... 
>>> import epydoc.docbuilder
>>> api = epydoc.docbuilder.build_doc(AggregateNode)
>>> api.variables['keys'].descr.to_plaintext(None)
u'List of fields according to which records are grouped\n\n'
>>> api.variables['record_count_field'].value.pyval
'record_count'
```

Comment: Thanks, good to know as this might be useful for some other projects. However, I do not need this for documentation purposes only. It will be used, for example, in UI form creation and automatic (protected) node configuration. I need more information for an @ivar than its description.

Comment: You can also use epydoc to specify its type and default value. Your example only gave a description; what other things do you need?

Comment: My bad about insufficient example. Besides default value(s) and type, there will be: protection scope or validation type/callable (currently implementing stuff that makes use of it). There are going to be more in the future, for sure.

Comment: You can also mention things like precondition or postcondition on most anything that is callable;  epydoc doesn't infer any meaning on that; but you could probably state it in terms of an expression that must be true to satisfy the condition; or as a python object that somehow represents the condition.

Answer (score 0):

The only element of a Python class able to modify the class definition itself (hence meta-data) is the `__new__()` function, new is called before the object is actually created, and before is initiated. You can use it to read/modify your classes/nodes internal structure before they gets initializated with `__init__()`